# microsoft odbc drivermanager SQLColAttribute SQL_INVALID_HANDLE

Tags: odbc

I'm getting SQL_INVALID_HANDLE error when calling SQLColAttribute from an application (trying to communicate with self developed odbc driver) I don't know why the handle is stated an invalid handle, since its a simple struct, which is still valid at runtime, ive checked it. The driver is a non unicode driver and im using it from a non unicode test application.

The driver also manages to set (log from the driver)

```
SQLGetStmtAttr called:
Attribute to set is: SQL_ATTR_APP_ROW_DESC
SQLGetStmtAttr called:
Attribute to set is: SQL_ATTR_APP_PARAM_DESC
SQLGetStmtAttr called:
Attribute to set is: SQL_ATTR_IMP_ROW_DESC
SQLGetStmtAttr called:
Attribute to set is: SQL_ATTR_IMP_PARAM_DESC
```

properly before calling sqlprepare

the driver manager log:

```
ODBC_Test       2210-151c   ENTER SQLAllocHandle 
    SQLSMALLINT                  1 <SQL_HANDLE_ENV>
    SQLHANDLE           0x00000000
    SQLHANDLE *         0x002EFCC0

ODBC_Test       2210-151c   EXIT  SQLAllocHandle  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
    SQLSMALLINT                  1 <SQL_HANDLE_ENV>
    SQLHANDLE           0x00000000
    SQLHANDLE *         0x002EFCC0 ( 0x003541C8)

ODBC_Test       2210-151c   ENTER SQLSetEnvAttr 
    SQLHENV             0x003541C8
    SQLINTEGER                 200 <SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION>
    SQLPOINTER                 3 <SQL_OV_ODBC3>
    SQLINTEGER                   0 

ODBC_Test       2210-151c   EXIT  SQLSetEnvAttr  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
    SQLHENV             0x003541C8
    SQLINTEGER                 200 <SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION>
    SQLPOINTER                 3 <SQL_OV_ODBC3>
    SQLINTEGER                   0 

ODBC_Test       2210-151c   ENTER SQLAllocHandle 
    SQLSMALLINT                  2 <SQL_HANDLE_DBC>
    SQLHANDLE           0x003541C8
    SQLHANDLE *         0x002EFCA8

ODBC_Test       2210-151c   EXIT  SQLAllocHandle  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
    SQLSMALLINT                  2 <SQL_HANDLE_DBC>
    SQLHANDLE           0x003541C8
    SQLHANDLE *         0x002EFCA8 ( 0x00354250)

ODBC_Test       2210-151c   ENTER SQLConnectW 
    HDBC                0x00354250
    WCHAR *             0x00352EB8 [       5] "dsn01"
    SWORD                        5 
    WCHAR *             0x55128B34 [      -3] "******\ 0"
    SWORD                       -3 
    WCHAR *             0x55128B34 [      -3] "******\ 0"
    SWORD                       -3 

ODBC_Test       2210-151c   EXIT  SQLConnectW  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
    HDBC                0x00354250
    WCHAR *             0x00352EB8 [       5] "dsn01"
    SWORD                        5 
    WCHAR *             0x55128B34 [      -3] "******\ 0"
    SWORD                       -3 
    WCHAR *             0x55128B34 [      -3] "******\ 0"
    SWORD                       -3 

ODBC_Test       2210-151c   ENTER SQLAllocHandle 
    SQLSMALLINT                  3 <SQL_HANDLE_STMT>
    SQLHANDLE           0x00354250
    SQLHANDLE *         0x002EF6F8

ODBC_Test       2210-151c   EXIT  SQLAllocHandle  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
    SQLSMALLINT                  3 <SQL_HANDLE_STMT>
    SQLHANDLE           0x00354250
    SQLHANDLE *         0x002EF6F8 ( 0x00355790)

ODBC_Test       2210-151c   ENTER SQLPrepare 
    HSTMT               0x00355790
    UCHAR *             0x00DB89C8 [      72] "select COUNTRYFR,CITYFROM,CITYTO from SPFLI where CITYFROM EQ 'NEW YORK'"
    SDWORD                    72

ODBC_Test       2210-151c   EXIT  SQLPrepare  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
    HSTMT               0x00355790
    UCHAR *             0x00DB89C8 [      72] "select COUNTRYFR,CITYFROM,CITYTO from SPFLI where CITYFROM EQ 'NEW YORK'"
    SDWORD                    72

ODBC_Test       2210-151c   ENTER SQLColAttribute 
    SQLHSTMT            0x00355790
    SQLSMALLINT                  1 
    SQLSMALLINT                 14 <SQL_DESC_TYPE_NAME>
    SQLPOINTER         0x002EF6B0
    SQLSMALLINT                 50 
    SQLSMALLINT *       0x002EF6A4
    SQLPOINTER          0x00000000 (NYI) 

ODBC_Test       2210-151c   ENTER SQLColAttribute 
    SQLHSTMT            0x00C05200
    SQLSMALLINT                  1 
    SQLSMALLINT                 14 <SQL_DESC_TYPE_NAME>
    SQLPOINTER         0x002EF6B0
    SQLSMALLINT                 50 
    SQLSMALLINT *       0x002EF6A4
    SQLPOINTER          0x00000000 (NYI) 

ODBC_Test       2210-151c   EXIT  SQLColAttribute  with return code -2 (SQL_INVALID_HANDLE)
    SQLHSTMT            0x00C05200
    SQLSMALLINT                  1 
    SQLSMALLINT                 14 <SQL_DESC_TYPE_NAME>
    SQLPOINTER         0x002EF6B0
    SQLSMALLINT                 50 
    SQLSMALLINT *       0x002EF6A4
    SQLPOINTER          0x00000000 (NYI) 

ODBC_Test       2210-151c   EXIT  SQLColAttribute  with return code -2 (SQL_INVALID_HANDLE)
    SQLHSTMT            0x00355790
    SQLSMALLINT                  1 
    SQLSMALLINT                 14 <SQL_DESC_TYPE_NAME>
    SQLPOINTER         0x002EF6B0
    SQLSMALLINT                 50 
    SQLSMALLINT *       0x002EF6A4
    SQLPOINTER          0x00000000 (NYI)
```

The test program is pretty simple:

```
SQLHANDLE hEnv ;

SQLAllocHandle( SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &hEnv ) ;

SQLSetEnvAttr( hEnv, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (void*)SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0 ) ; 

SQLHANDLE hConn ;

SQLAllocHandle( SQL_HANDLE_DBC, hEnv, &hConn );


SQLCHAR* dsnName = (SQLCHAR*)"dsn01" ;  // MUST BE THE SAME
SQLCHAR* userid = (SQLCHAR*)"nodata\0";
SQLCHAR* password = (SQLCHAR*)"nodata\0"; 

SQLConnect(

hConn,
dsnName, 
5, 
userid, 
SQL_NTS,
password, 
SQL_NTS);


HSTMT hStmt ;
SQLAllocHandle( SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hConn, &hStmt ) ;

SQLCHAR* query = (SQLCHAR*)"select COUNTRYFR,CITYFROM,CITYTO from SPFLI where CITYFROM EQ 'NEW YORK'";

SQLPrepare(hStmt,query,strlen((const char*)query));

SQLCHAR TypeName[50];
SQLSMALLINT TypeNameLen;

SQLColAttribute((SQLHSTMT)hStmt,1,SQL_DESC_TYPE_NAME,TypeName, sizeof(TypeName),&TypeNameLen,NULL);
```

Anyone knows what can cause SQLColAttribute to give back SQL_INVALID_HANDLE ? I've read msdn but nothing useful was there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You allocated a statement handle which is 0x00355790. You prepared it. It all goes wrong as you say when you call SQLColAttribute. The log suggests that SQLColAttribute was called correctly with the statement handle but then (your driver?) called SQLColAttribute again with a different handle. My guess is you've got a function name clash in your driver.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but i'm a 100% sure that SQLColAttribute doesn't get called from my driver at all. That is the drivermanagers log, that you can see here, as it translates my 1 SQLColAttribute call from the test application into 2 calls in the air (one with the still valid statement handle and one with his own wrapper handle) returning sql_invalid_handle. If the drivermanager would call into my driver i could see it in the drivers log. Am i wrong?

Comment: I realise it is a driver manager log. However, with a working driver a call from an app to SQLColAttribute would only be logged once (well twice really, but one is entry and one is exit). You need to look at the handle (the incorrect one) passed in the second SQLColAttribute call and see who created it or what is at that location. The log defintely makes it look like SQLColAttribute was called twice as if your driver is calling it with its own handle.

Comment: I've just tried it again on Windows with my working ODBC driver (I wrote) and one call to SQLColAttribute ends it a single log entry with the correct handle. Occassionally my driver needs to call its own ODBC API not via the driver manager and to achieve this it has 2 entry points SQLxxx which the driver manager calls but this simply calls _SQLxxx and so my driver can call _SQLxxx if it wants to bypass the driver manager.

Comment: Do you know if there are any prequesites for SQLColAttribute to work properly? I've an interesting thing going on in my driver, once i call SQLAllochandle from the test, which automatically calls SQLGetStmtAttr 4 times in the driver to get the implicitly allocated descriptors, when i recast the statement handle after the calls are finished i find out that the descriptors default values got changed by the drivermanager. How is that even possible? The drivermanager can't know my structure of descriptors.

Comment: Currently i'm trying to track back the value represented by that memory location you suggested, no luck yet

Comment: I've managed to debug some of the error. If with SQLGetinfo case SQL_DRIVER_ODBC_VER i return "02.00" instead od "03.00", the issue goes away and no SQLGetStmtAttr calls are made. I guess this has something to do with how the drivermanager translates calls from 3.8 to 3.0 and 2.0. I don't want my driver to be 2.0 though

Comment: I've solved the problem:

the declaration of the function SQLColAttribute found on msdn is not correct: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms713558(v=vs.85).aspx

since arg6 must be SQLPOINTER. I was using that declaration. The error SQL_INVALID_HANDLE though was .... a little inappropriate too. I Will mark your first opinion as a sollution to the problem since i had somewhat a function name clash.

Answer (score 2):

See this declaration in sqlucode.h :

```
// UNICODE versions
#ifdef _WIN64
SQLRETURN SQL_API SQLColAttributeW
(
    SQLHSTMT        hstmt,
    SQLUSMALLINT    iCol,
    SQLUSMALLINT    iField,
    _Out_writes_bytes_opt_(cbDescMax)
    SQLPOINTER      pCharAttr,
    SQLSMALLINT     cbDescMax,
    _Out_opt_
    SQLSMALLINT     *pcbCharAttr,
    _Out_opt_
    SQLLEN          *pNumAttr
);
#else
SQLRETURN SQL_API SQLColAttributeW(
    SQLHSTMT        hstmt,
    SQLUSMALLINT    iCol,
    SQLUSMALLINT    iField,
    _Out_writes_bytes_opt_(cbDescMax)
    SQLPOINTER      pCharAttr,
    SQLSMALLINT     cbDescMax,
    _Out_opt_
    SQLSMALLINT     *pcbCharAttr,
    _Out_opt_
    SQLPOINTER      pNumAttr);
#endif
```

and understand how difficult it is

- > (for me) to avoid the *function name clash* in both cases (x64/x86)
- > (for microsoft) to write correct doc